What's the movie that has a couple deceiving another couple
Around 2014/2015 I saw a movie that opened with a lovely couple backpacking around a Caribbean island. Viewers immediately bonded with this couple. This couple met another couple and proceeded to show this new couple around the islands.
At one point in the movie, the man in the first couple jumped about 30m into an underground lake, beckoning the second couple to follow. It was kind of a trust test.
During the course of the film, it transpired that the villains were not the second couple but the first. This was a bit of a shock because the movie opened with the first couple; the viewer bonded with this couple.
What's the name of the movie?

It sounds similar to (A Perfect Getaway, 2009), starring Milla Jovovich, Steve Zahn, Timothy Olyphant and Kiele Sanchez. IMDB

Plot:   (Wikipedia)

A young mild-mannered American couple, Cliff (Zahn) and Cydney
  (Jovovich), are celebrating their marriage by hiking to a remote beach
  in Hawaii while on their honeymoon. On their way, they see two
  hitchhikers, Cleo (Shelton) and Kale (Chris Hemsworth). They offer the
  pair a ride but change their minds when the two seem possibly
  dangerous.
After they begin the hike, the couple comes in contact with Nick
  (Olyphant), a solo hiker who claims to be an Iraq War veteran. Nick
  saves Cydney's life when she slips while attempting to cross a narrow
  ledge. The trio approaches a group of frightened female hikers
  discussing a double murder in Honolulu. The victims had their teeth
  pulled out and fingertips removed. Cliff suspects the hitchhiking
  couple are the murderers, and Cydney and Cliff discuss whether or not
  they should turn back, but decide to continue hiking with Nick. They
  subsequently meet up with Nick's sexy girlfriend, Gina (Sanchez) at
  the Secret Falls Waterfall.
Cliff suspects Kale and Cleo are following them. When he notices their
  permits are missing, Cliff sees Kale and Cleo's bags by the trail and
  goes through them, but he does not find the permits. After making
  camp, Nick and Cliff split up to search for Kale and Cleo. Cliff runs
  into a guide who is bringing Cliff the permits they left behind. Cliff
  and Nick return to the campsite. Nick brings a goat he has killed, and
  Gina proceeds to butcher the animal, explaining she had learned how
  while working in the meat department of a grocery store.
The following day, Kale and Cleo are arrested for the murders. A
  container full of pulled teeth is found in one of their bags. The two
  couples are relieved by the arrests, and they continue their hike to
  the beach. Cliff rents two kayaks so he and Nick can explore a marine
  cave.
As Gina idly looks through the photos on Cydney and Cliff's video
  camera, she is terrified when she realizes the couple are not who they
  claim to be. Gina sets off after Nick and Cliff, while Cydney chases
  after Gina.
Flashbacks reveal that Cliff and Cydney are drug-addicted sociopaths
  who murdered the newlyweds. They kill people and steal their
  identities in order to, as Cliff explains, "live a hundred different
  lives and achieve a kind of immortality". It is also revealed that
  "Cliff" had planted the bag of teeth in Kale and Cleo's bag to frame
  them for the murders.
In the Sea cave, Cliff suddenly reveals his true murderer identity and
  shoots Nick in the head. Gina witnesses this from the cliffs above.
  Then Cliff shoots at her, but misses. Cydney sneaks up on Gina and
  attacks her. Gina is stabbed in the leg but manages to push Cydney off
  the cliff into the water.
Even though they haven't had a signal during the entire trip, Gina
  fortuitously receives a call on her cell phone from a phone company
  representative. She begs him to call the police. She spots Cydney
  below in the kayak just as Cliff pops up over the cliff ledge to grab
  her feet. Gina stabs him in the hand with Cydney's knife and flees.
While Cliff chases Gina and Cydney kayaks ashore to intercept the
  police, Nick, saved by the titanium plate in his head from his war
  wound, wakes up. Gina runs into a group of men searching for their
  stolen kayaks, who tell her she is safe now. Cliff tries to convince
  the men that Gina is irrational due to meth use. But one of the group
  happens to be an EMT and notices Cliff's enlarged pupils, which
  undermines his story, so Cliff shoots and kills the entire group of
  men. Gina uses Cliff's distraction as an opportunity to run toward the
  beach. Nick arrives and fights Cliff, getting the upper hand. At that
  point, the police arrive by helicopter with a rifle aimed at Nick.
  Cydney is also in the helicopter, and the police want her to confirm
  that Nick is the killer, but she pauses. Cydney identifies Cliff as
  the murderer and says he ruined her life. The police sharpshooter
  kills Cliff as he reaches for his gun to kill Nick. Later Nick finally
  proposes to Gina in the helicopter but due to their traumatic
  encounters, they both agree to not having a honeymoon.

Trailer
Clip


